# What does bind-source-addr do?

Tags: redis

I am reading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/redis/redis/7.0/redis.conf, and I am having trouble understanding the difference between ‘bind’ and ‘bind-source-addr’. With respect to client-server TCP connections, it seems like the former lists the allowable client IPs and the latter declares a server IP. Is that right, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it seems like the former lists the allowable client IPs and the latter declares a server IP

Wrong.

Redis instance is both a TCP server and TCP client. As a server, it serves request from user. As a client, it needs to connect to its master (replica mode), monitored instance (sentinel mode), or other Redis nodes (cluster mode).

`bind` is used for being a server, while `bind-source-addr` is used for being a client.

`bind` lists IPs on which Redis listens (when acting as a server). So that clients can connect to Redis with these IPs.

`bind-source-addr` lists IP to which Redis binds (when acting as a client). So that when Redis needs to connect to other Redis nodes, the connection is created with the given IP specified with `bind-source-addr`.